# Running Xcode 4.01 and 4.2 on the same computer?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5

I am currently running Xcode 4.02 to develop my production products for release to the AppStore. My normal dev system is an i7 iMac and I also use a MBP when away from my office. I want to start testing development for iOS 5 so have downloaded the Xcode 4.2 package and iOS 5 beta and first plan to install it on a my only other Mac, an original MBA that I know from experience of developing on it in a pinch (when my traveling MPB was down and had the MBA sent to me) will be pretty (actually, *really*) slow.

Preferring of course to have a fast dev system, my question is, can I *safely* install the Xcode 4.2 developer preview and the iOS 5 beta on my iMac and/or MBP without screwing up my production development environment?  I see from the 4.2 release notes that "You can have multiple versions of the Xcode toolset installed.", I assume by installing Xcode 4.2 in a different -Xcode- directory. What make me wary is that the release notes also state that "NOTE: Only one version of the System Tools ... can be installed on a computer at a time. The last installed set of these components replaces any previously installed set."

So is it a good or bad idea to have both Xcode installs on the same computer at the same time or should I stick with installing 4.2 on a different machine and if I really need to have a more powerful system, consider getting a newer box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, you just need to install in a different directory. `Developer` is the default, you just need to change it.

As for the System Tools, as far as I know they don't interfere in you ability to release apps to the AppStore. Still, you can uncheck them when installing and Xcode 4.2 will use Xcode 4.0 System Tools without problem (that's what I have right now).